# Software for forensic analysis

Tags: windows, gratis, windows-registry

I am looking for software, which helps with forensic analysis of .exe-files, especially, if the analysied file

- modifies the registry
- creates, modifies or deletes other files
- opens network connections
- starts threads or processes

Since i am just doing this as a hobby, i am not willing to spend money on the software. So far i only know PEstudio, which is not bad, but has not that many functions.
I am thankful for any recommendations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use [CAINE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAINE_Linux) (Computer Aided Investigative Environment)

CAINE offers a complete forensic environment that is organized to integrate existing software tools as software modules and to provide a friendly graphical interface.

You can install it on a USB stick or on a Virtual Machine.

Comment: thanks, i will take a look into it. looks promising